# How can I take a candlelit photo with a pure black background?

Tags: lighting, portrait, candlelight

[image]

I was trying out the same shot but was unable to achieve such lighting on the subject. Also My background becomes visible If I start playing around with the exposure. i.e. if my exposure is balanced I can see the background, if I under expose my shot the subject becomes dark. What kind of settings are used to get a snap like this ?

Comment: FWIW it seems likely that the background was made dark by editing - this is not certain but the massivelyt gamma-upped version seen [**here**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wZhFm.jpg) suggests so.

Comment: Also, by replacing the black background which has RGB values of 2,2,4 with pure white with a colour difference tolerance of 1 (so only essentially identically coloured  pixels atre replaced, you get the same pattern as in the gamma-upped version showing where the background has been "pasted" with black. See [**HERE**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YdESn.jpg)

Comment: Just to be clear: when you say "smooth", you mean the effect where the subject is illuminated but the background us dark, as you describe? Or do you mean something additional by that?

Comment: @mattdm I meant the lighting on the subject is so clear but the background is not visible. But, when I try it out I even get the background.

Comment: @Russell, do you think that's selective editing, or a global curves adjustment?

Comment: @mattdm COULD be curves- and at the extreme limit they are much the same thing, but I think it was editing. But, of course, I may be wrong :-). I just had another play - and it still looks like an edit - and I still may be wrong :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I think you should put all of this as an answer.

Comment: Are you using real candles or the LED tea lights like in the sample photo?  Real candles don't provide the same color temperature and brightness as the LEDs.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I was using real candles itself. May be that is the reason I wasn't able to achieve that brightness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to tell with this small version, but the image might be a composition of two images. If there were several candles lighting the person I would expect multiple shadow lines, eg. from the arm. One could also have a look at the catchlight in the eyes in a high-res version.

To get the background dark enough, in addition to the other suggestions, you need to shut out all other light. You can expose a shot without the candles for the highest exposure to know what your limit is. Then you can add candles to illuminate the subject as much as needed. the background should almost not be affected since the light intensity falls off proportional to 1/r².

Comment: +1 for the catchlight in the eyes, that's a great place to look for clues on lighting setup

Comment: It could have been a single image, there are least 8 candles there, possibly more behind, so slow enough shutter and sitting very still it's obviously achievable. It looks like most of the candles are (at least approximately) on a plane parallel to the camera, with the exception of one that seems to be quite a way forward, so this may explain why you don't have the multiple shadow lines on the upper arm/shoulder

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to have a real black background behind your subject, and then be sure that your subject is quite distant from it. Now, by exposing correctly on your subject's skin, you should obtain the result you like.

Comment: IMHO you do not need exactly black background. As far as it is not illuminated and you have enough distance to it you can use any neutral background